# Fail to connect to remote Postgres docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I used official Postgres image and created my container,and I can connect to Postgres in the container successfully locally by port 5432 and created my own tables and inserted data.But I cannot access Postgres from remote machine in the same local ether network.

I have set a shell script called `access.sh` to write `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` to pg_hba.conf. And I placed access.sh in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/access.sh` directory so that in my understanding it will be executed when the container starts.

Comment: How are you creating your container? What `docker run` command did you used?

Comment: Is the port 5432 exposed when the container is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon the container starts,it says"IPv4 forwarding is disabled,networking will not work".

Solutions:

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1  

#restart network and docker

systemctl restart network && systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run your container with the following:
docker run -p 5432:5432 "containerid" 
Could you pls confirm if you do?
Also postgres db should not be running on your host machine at the same time (should not occupy the port)
On windows you can do: net stop postgresql-9.0
On linux there're multiple distributives with different options. Please share more context about your env to help you out.